# Orchard CMS - Remove Title and Metadata(published date) in a post

Tags: orchardcms

How do I remove the Title and Metadata(published data) in a post? Can this be done in Placement.info? I tried creating a custom content but doesn't look like a best solution. I just done it with CSS but I know this could be done in another way.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can edit the `Placement.info` file in your current theme's root folder to not display the title and publish date:

```
<Placement>
    <Match DisplayType="Detail">
        <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
    </Match>
    <Match DisplayType="Summary">
        <Place Parts_Title="-"/>            
        <Place Parts_Common_Metadata="-"/>
    </Match>
</Placement>
```

See this post for further details: [Orchard: Anatomy of a theme](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Anatomy-of-a-theme)

Also, in case you are wondering where names like `Parts_Title` come from, see [Customizing Orchard using the Designer Helper Tools](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools) (specifically shape tracing).

Comment: great info! Parts_RoutableTitle didn't work so I tried Parts_Title and the title was gone. I think because I made a custom content.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll update the answer too to reflect this.

Comment: Right I have another question. what about doing the same thing from different Content Type? e.g. I have 2 different Content Types and both has Title. I want to show the Title for the 1st Content Type and the 2nd not.

Comment: Sorry - I got it. I used ContentType instead of DisplayType

Comment: Wow, thanks @scripni that saved my day! (week). The Shape Alternate module now also comes great in place. Totally new, but after reading the http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Customizing-Orchard-using-Designer-Helper-Tools I can easily overwrite Core shapes to my Theme and customize them.

Comment: In my case I just wanted to remove the title from the home page...     <Match Path="/">
        <Place Parts_Title="-"/>
</Match>

Answer (score 15):

Alternatively, if you want to keep the title meta in the head whilst removing the title on every page create a Parts.Title.cshtml file in the view folder of your theme and then put

```
@{
Layout.Title = Model.Title;
}
```

which is exactly the same as the normal code except we remove the `<h1>` tag

```
@{
Layout.Title = Model.Title;
}

<h1>@Model.Title</h1>
```