# remove header tag from Orchard CMS widget

Tags: orchardcms

Removing  tag from the default widget not working by using any of the templates it appears (eg widget.cshtml/common) templates.

(not duplicate of [Orchard CMS - Remove Title and Metadata(published date) in a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9770709/orchard-cms-remove-title-and-metadatapublished-date-in-a-post))

Also overriding widget.cshtml doesnt appear to work as  and is wrapper around this/inserted. 
Appears no doc on using Placement.info to do this either.. Appreciate any ideas..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override **Widget.Wrapper.cshtml** in your theme.

The original one can be found in **/Modules/Orchard.Widgets/Views/**

Comment: Thank You, 
[note: may need to 'include in project' /code/ directory in order to view widget.wrapper.cshtml in shape tracer and index for file search [CTL + ,]